# How to display register in CKAN

Tags: ckan

I have a problem with the registration , i can't see register beside login in the main page it disappeared,

and if i want to access the /user/register page, it redirects me to this url like :

```
http://www.example.com/user/login?came_from=http://www.example.com
/user/register
```

here is the development.ini configuration :

```
ckan.auth.anon_create_dataset = false
ckan.auth.create_unowned_dataset = false
ckan.auth.create_dataset_if_not_in_organization = false
ckan.auth.user_create_groups = true
ckan.auth.user_create_organizations = true
ckan.auth.user_delete_groups = true
ckan.auth.user_delete_organizations = true
ckan.auth.create_user_via_api = true
ckan.auth.create_user_via_web = true
ckan.auth.roles_that_cascade_to_sub_groups = admin
```

if you can see the `ckan.auth.create_user_via_web` is `true`.

What should i do to overcome this problem ???

Comment: Any help community ????

Comment: Did you restart apache after changing the config?

Answer (score 0):

The "Register" link is shown if the auth function `user_create` is True, which relies on the config option `create_user_via_web` which I see you have as True. So I'm pretty sure that Ross's comment is correct, that you need to restart CKAN (i.e. apache or paster) for your update config to take effect.